# Is there a php framework that includes authentication with Facebook and Google+?

Tags: php, facebook, frameworks, google-plus

It seems like every contract job now requires authentication using Facebook and Google Plus. Is there a well-supported php framework that natively supports Facebook and Google plus auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well no specifically frameworks, there are however packages and plugins for frameworks. I would suggest this for Facebook, Google and a multitude of other third-party websites.

http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think every framework has a Facebook, Google+ Plugin, you just need to choose which framework suits your project.

If you want to see a plugin for facebook auth that i did long time ago for Kohana 2.

Check it here [facebook-connect](https://github.com/Faianca/Facebook-Connect)